# The pytest test always return abc.is_online True

Tags: django, unit-testing, django-rest-framework, pytest, pytest-django

**The test always return abc.is_online True. But abc.is_online should be False because celery task makes is_online False after 60 second from now.**
**Error Meassge: assert True == False
where True = <ABC: Charles Reyes>.is_online**

```
@app.task(name="task.abc_last_active") #Celery task
def abc_last_active():
    now = timezone.localtime()

    for xyz in ABC.objects.all():
        if not xyz.last_active:
            continue

        elapsed = now - xyz.last_active

        if elapsed.total_seconds() >= settings.ABC_TIMEOUT: #60 Sec
            xyz.is_online = False
            xyz.save()

@pytest.fixture
def create_abc():
    abc = ABC.objects.create(
        phone="123234432",
        location=Point(1, 4),
        last_active=timezone.localtime() - timezone.timedelta(seconds=162),
        is_online=True,
    )
    return abc

@pytest.mark.django_db
def test_inactive_abc_gets_deactivated(create_abc):
    print(create_abc.is_online, "before deactivation")

    abc_last_active()

    print(create_abc.is_online, "after deactivation")
    assert create_abc.is_online == False
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `create_abc.refresh_from_db()` after running that Celery task. Django won't hit the database here and there each time the obj is changed.

**EDIT:** Improve answer to clarify what's going on here.

You create a new object *in a memory* here (which is now *saved into DB*):

```py
def create_abc():
    ...
```

then a celery task takes the *DB object* and creates *a new one* in a memory (old one `create_abc` in a test closure remains old by that point).
After a task is completed, the fixture object that is *in memory* knows nothing about the new one *in the DB*. So you must load a fresh DB instance to your old obj by calling `refresh_from_db()` on it.

For tests, I would recommend instead of refreshing (because you can forget to refresh) create assertions that explicitly use fresh instances and develop such a habit to avoid problems in the future. I.e.:

```py
@pytest.mark.django_db
def test_inactive_abc_gets_deactivated(create_abc):
    ...
    assert ABC.objects.first().is_online == False
```

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more?